# How to access updated state value in same function that used to set state value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

```
class Signup extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { count: 0 }
  }

  hndlChange() {
    //here it's okay, It increasing count value
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });

    //but here it printing previous value
    console.log(this.state.count);

  }
}
```

I am calling this function. As it is increasing `count` value but when I access this it return previous value. i wan to access latest updated value in same function what should i do for that.

**How to access latest state value in same function**

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As stated [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) React has additional `callback` parameter.

Also, when you want to mutate your state using current value you should use function version:

```
this.setState(currentState => ({ count: currentState.count + 1 }), () => {
    console.log(this.state.count);
});
```

Comment: this.setState(currentState => ({ count: currentState.count + 1 }), {
    console.log(this.state.count);
});   yah its is the recommended way to update previous state, but  i want to get latest value. in your case it showing Unexpected token, expected , ERROR

Comment: this.setState(currentState => ({ count: currentState.count + 1 }),function() {
    console.log(this.state.count);
});   now its work fine. Thanks @pwolaq

Comment: @KailashChoudhary I forgot about `() =>` before function body

Comment: what about useState() hook updater?

Answer (score 2):

```
 hndlChange();
{
  //here it's okay, It increasing count value
  this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 }, () => {});
}
```

set state is asynchronous.