# React this.setState is undefined inside handlechange

Tags: reactjs, state

I have a dropdown for search via location

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
     
      formData:{ }
    };

  
    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
  }

 <div class="form-group emp-searc-location ">
            <select id="emp_location"  onChange={this.handleSelect} name="emp_location" value={this.state.formData.emp_location} class="form-control">
              <option value="">Select Location name</option>
              {this.state.emplocation.map(({ branch_location, id }, index) => (
                <option value={branch_location}>{branch_location}</option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </div>
```

And my function

```
handleSelect=async(e)=>{
   
    
    this.setState({
      formData: {
        ...this.state.formData,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      },
    });
    
    console.log(this.state.formData);
             
  }
```

And formData seems empty.but when i console `console.log(e.target.value)` i got correct value.but when i console  `console.log(this.state.formData);` i got empty value.any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the docs, `setState` has an additional callback parameter: [React - setState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

You can utilize the callback parameter and check the updated state there.

See also: [how-to-access-updated-state-value-in-same-function-that-used-to-set-state-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48319251/how-to-access-updated-state-value-in-same-function-that-used-to-set-state-value)

Also, may I know if the async keyword is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, The value will be properly assigned to state. But If you put     `console.log(this.state.formData);` immediately after `setState`. The value will not be replicated. For this, You can put `console.log` inside `componentDidUpdate()` like,

```
componentDidUpdate() {
   console.log(this.state.formData);
}
```

You can check the value using the `componentDidUpdate()`.